# How does the replicas in kafka works if one broker went done for 2 hours and came back?

Tags: apache-kafka

we are having 3 zookeeper and 3 kafka broker nodes as cluster setup running in different systems in AWS,And we changes the below properties to ensure the high availabilty and prevent data loss.

server.properties

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
```

i am having the following question
Assume BROKER A,B,C

since we are enabling replication factor as 3 all the data will be available in all A,B,C brokers if A broker is down it wont affect the flow.

but when ever broker A went down but at the same time we are continously receiving data from connector and it is storing the broker B and C

so after 2 hours broker A came up

In that time the data came between the down time and up time of A is available in broker A or not?

is there any specific configuration we need to mention for that?

how does the replication between the broker happen when one broker came online from offline?

i didn't know whether it is a valid question, but please share your thoughts on this to understand this replication factor working

Answer (score 1):

While A is recovering, it'll be out of the ISR list. If you've disabled unclean leader election, then A cannot become the leader broker of any partitions it holds (no client can write or read to it) and will replicate data from other replicas until its up to date, then join the ISR

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, i am taking like the recovering broker will **replicate the data automatically** from the other broker and after that only it will join the ISR.No need from our end to keep the recovering broker up to date.Am i correct?

Comment: Outside of external events like network partitions or similar causes for the recovering broker being unable to reach the others, then, yes